# Call a function inside the const function in react

Tags: reactjs, function, jsx

I have a function1 and function2 inside the `const function1`.
How can I call the `function2()` and `function3()` in the function1?

```
const function1 = ({par1, par2) => {

    function funtion2(text) {
        <div>function 2: {text}</div>
    }

    const function3 = (text) => <div>function 3 {text}</div>

    return (
         <div>
             call function2: {function2("some text")}
             call function3: {function3("some text")}
         </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is this not working in some way?  Are you getting an error?  Unexpected output?  Something else?

Comment: i didnt get any output from the function.

Comment: @Dhanapal: Didn't get any output from *which* function?  Be specific about how you're even using this code in the first place.  Currently nothing calls `function1` or displays any output.  The code you're showing also has a syntax error on the first line, so clearly this wouldn't generate any output at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function2` and `function3` declarations shouldn't be nested inside `function1` because they don't depend on its scope.

`function2` doesn't return anything.

`function1`, `function2` and `function3` act as functional components and should be used as such; they should have pascal case names and have single `props` parameter:

```
function Funtion2({ text }) {
    return <div>function 2: {text}</div>
}

const Function3 = ({ text }) => <div>function 3 {text}</div>

const Function1 = ({ par1, par2 }) => {
    return (
         <div>
             <Function2 text={"some text"}/>
             <Function3 text={"some text"}/>
         </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: "...and have single props parameter". Not exactly since you could pass multiple `props`

Comment: `props` can be used to pass multiple values as object keys with destructuring (this is what's shown in the post), but it's still only 1 parameter in function signature. The point was that a function shouldn't have `function Foo(val1, val2)` signature because it's incompatible with component function signature.